# What is fieldno in Tarantool space config?

Tags: config, tarantool

Extract from the config:

```
space[0].index[0].type = "TREE"
space[0].index[0].unique = 1
space[0].index[0].key_field[0].fieldno = 0
space[0].index[0].key_field[0].type = "STR"
```

What does **fieldno** mean? Failed to find clear answer in the [docs](https://tarantool.org/doc/search.html?q=fieldno&check_keywords=yes&area=default).

Comment: Found the answer in the [old docs](http://stable.tarantool.org/doc/user_guide.html) though.

Comment: You're looking at an old version of the server. This configuration file is from version 1.5, and 1.6 is not compatible with it. Please use a never distro or install from Tarantool official upstream: 
https://tarantool.org/download.html

There is a historical link to 1.5 manual that is still available:
http://stable.tarantool.org/doc/mpage/index.html